Is it legitimate to ask a potential claimant in a class action settlement not to contact the court to inquire about it?
I have seen an email from a lawyer telling the recipient that they may be entitled to money from a class action settlement. After quite a few paragraphs about this, it says:

PLEASE DO NOT CONTACT THE COURT OR THE COURT CLERK’S OFFICE TO INQUIRE ABOUT THIS SETTLEMENT OR THE CLAIM PROCESS.

Whom else would one contact to ask whether this is legitimate? Are notices like that normally included in emails from plaintiff's lawyers in class actions?

If this is another take on "You've won the Canadian Lottery" or "Your firm may be due for Covid compensation", then of course they don't want you to contact the court, because there is no "class action". You could look up the source of your email and contact them directly, to verify the claim (not via an email link).

I think this is meant as a courtesy to the clerk and not an actual command.

This is standard and appears on any notice of class action settlement I've ever gotten. The clerk cannot tell you anything about the case. The clerk can confirm the case existence, but you can look that up yourself too.
You can look the case up on the internet, there are some aggregator websites specializing in that as well (e.g.: this one or this one, no affiliation). That can help you confirming the contact details.
